# Can a C function modify the value of its input arguments in the calling function?

Tags: c

Can a C function modify the value of its input arguments in the calling function?

Could you provide an example.

Comment: Not without pointers. C is not pass by reference, it's pass by value.

Answer (score 1):

Not without pointers. C is not pass by reference, it's pass by value.

Here's a trivial example with pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int reassign_argc(int *argc)
{
    return *argc = 7;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc == 7) argc = 3;
    reassign_argc(&argc);
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

if the argument is the pointer, the answer is yes, else no.

classic swap 2 numbers function in C is a good example.

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int t;
    t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

usage:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
swap(&a, &b);
```